# Metodo Json - Retorno

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Estou desenvolvendo um retorno de CEPs através da API dos correios, a parte que está no controller está funcionando, mas não sei se o retorno está correto, e nem como fazer para utilizar na view. Se alguém puder me dar uma Luz fico Grato.

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult RetornaEndereco(string cep)
    {
        var valor = cep;
        var ws = new WSCorreios.AtendeClienteClient();
        var resposta = ws.consultaCEP(valor);
        try
        {

            System.Console.WriteLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Endereço: {0}", resposta.end);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Complemento: {0}", resposta.complemento);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Complemento 2: {0}", resposta.complemento2);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Bairro: {0}", resposta.bairro);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Cidade: {0}", resposta.cidade);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Estado: {0}", resposta.uf);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Unidades de Postagem: {0}", resposta.unidadesPostagem);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("Erro ao efetuar busca do CEP: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(resposta);
    }
```

O Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cep").blur(function () {
            var cepValue = $(cep).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'RetornaEndereco',
                data: { cep: cepValue },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = data;
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('Error' + data);
                    obj = JSON.parse(text);
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                    obj.data.cep;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema aí é que tu tá tratando o retorno onde deve tratar erro de requisição, da forma abaixo funciona, também não precisa fazer parse para Json, o jquery já devolve pronto.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cep").blur(function () {
        var cepValue = $(cep).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'RetornaEndereco',
            data: { cep: cepValue },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                                        
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.cep;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error' + data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @FernandoRomano não me atentei a isto.

Comment: É nois! A maioria dos problemas são pequenos detalhes.

Answer (score 1):

> A parte que está no controller está funcionando

Ok, mas aqueles `System.Console.WriteLine` são completamente desnecessários. Outra coisa, retornar `ex.Message` quando ocorrer um erro **pode** ser um problema. Dessa forma você retorna só a mensagem principal, toda as outras informações sobre o erro vão embora.

> mas não sei se o retorno está correto

Se o método no *controller* está correto, o retorno está correto. Desde que **`resposta`** seja um objeto, ele será retornado.

> e nem como fazer para utilizar na view.

É fácil. No ajax tem o *callback* `success`, ele recebe como parâmetro o retorno da requisição pro servidor. Aí é só você usar as propriedades que o objeto `resposta` (lá do servidor) tem.

```
success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("txt-cep").innerHTML = data.cep;
}
```